# Donde vieram os "cornos" da traição sexual?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

Um homem cuja companheira faz uns biscates por fora é “corno” ou “cornudo”; se tem conhecimento e se conforma é “corno manso”. E diz-se que a mulher lhe “põe os cornos”. O homem também pode “pôr os cornos” à mulher, mas não me parece comum dizer-se que a mulher é “cornuda” ou “corno” ou “corna”.

Agora, donde é que vem esta terminologia e quando é que aparece na língua escrita? Terá sido invenção nossa ou inspirou-se noutra língua?

Comment: Só para a cronaca, em italiano também se diz "cornuto", "mettere le corna" (ou seja "põe os cornos"), portanto deve derivar de algo antigo (tempo do latim?) mas não necessariamente.

Answer (score 3):

[Corno](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corno) são apêndices da cabeça de alguns mamíferos, popularmente conhecido como chifres, porém chifre são encontrados em veados e cervos. Já expressão corno, indicando que é  uma pessoa traída, surgiu de uma lenda que diz que a cabeça da pessoa traída começou a doer na região da testa, então os populares disseram que os cornos estavam nascendo.

A origem do termos existem algumas teorias:

- Na Europa medieval, o homem traído deveria lavar a honra com sangue, matando a esposa e o amante, caso falhasse, era hostilizado, recebendo uma peruca de touro, com dois chifres.
- Os tratadores dos animais, perceberam que o boi que perdia território (vítima da chifrada), além de perder o território, ficava sem as vacas daquele local, assim, foi feita a associação ente o homem traído e boi chifrado, dando origem a expressão "chifre ao traído".
- A outra teoria e que acreditam ser a mais provável é que esteja ligada à cultura da Grécia. Isso porque, Zeus, que exercia a autoridade sobre os deuses olímpicos na antiga religião grega, vivia traindo sua esposa (Hera) e para traí-la ele se fantasiava de touro e passava por ela com chifres enormes, fazendo com que ela não desconfiasse do marido.

Mas lembre-se que "isso tudo é coisa que colocam na sua cabeça."

**Não há consenso entre os historiadores sobre a origem do termo.**

Referência:

- [Wikipédia - Corno (gíria)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corno_(g%C3%ADria))
- [Por que chamamos de corno aquele que é traído?](http://super.abril.com.br/blog/oraculo/por-que-chamamos-de-corno-aquele-que-e-traido/)
- [História e curiosidade](http://historiaesuascuriosidades.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/corno-chifre-e-traicao-conheca-origem.html)

Comment: Há uma "indústria" a inventar origens de palavras e expressões, e é preciso separar o trigo do joio. Quando um site diz que a origem é esta ou aquela, a pergunta óbvia é: como é que eles sabem? Se eles não dão uma resposta a essa pergunta, é melhor esquecer. Por exemplo, essa tal lenda, que davam ao marido corneado uma peruca com cornos. Como é que nós sabemos que essa lenda de facto existiu? Aparece num livro? Em que século? Em que sítio? Eles não dizem nada, portanto eu não dou crédito nenhum a essa história.

Comment: @Jacinto, em relação as lendas não tem como falar a data certa, lendas eram utilizadas para explicar fatos que as pessoas não sabiam como aconteciam. Fiz até uma [pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4092/como-surgiram-as-lendas) sobre isso.

Comment: Tais, Se a lenda de facto existiu (se não foi uma invenção de quem escreveu o site) então deve ser possível dizer qualquer coisa como, "esta lenda já era conhecida pelo menos a partir do ano X, porque há um livro publicado no ano X (com título Y, do autor W, publicado na cidade Z) que fala da lenda". Por exemplo havia em Portugal no século XIX várias lendas acerca do arco-íris; eu sei isso porque [este livro de 1882](https://archive.org/stream/tradiespopulare00vascgoog#page/n9/mode/2up) fala dessas lendas. Mas os teus sites não explicam como é sabem as coisas que lá dizem...

Comment: @Jacinto, desconheço algum livro que possa afirmar com certeza desde quando surgiu alguma lenda. Gostei desse livro que você mandou o link, porém, sobre essa resposta, acrescentei uma frase falando que não há consenso entre os historiadores sobre a origem do termo.

Comment: Tais, a questão é, eu posso fazer um site e dizer: existe há vários séculos uma lenda que os vikings no século X quando atacavam aldeias portuguesas, na confusão iam para a cama com as mulheres portuguesas; quando os marido os descobriam, os vinkings com pressa fugiam e deixavam o capacete com os cornos, e é daí que vem a expressão pôr os cornos. Pronto, eu acabei de inventar isto; mas se eu não te dissesse, como é que sabias se esta lenda existiu mesmo?

Comment: @Jacinto, você está correto, qualquer um pode escrever um artigo em um blog "inventando" uma lenda.  Dificilmente você verá uma data correta para uma lenda, porém existem exceções, conforme mencionado por você no seu comentário. Sobre essa não posso afirmar, pois conforme destaquei na resposta e comentei não há consenso entre os historiadores. E as lendas geralmente eram contadas para explicar acontecimentos dos quais as pessoas não sabiam a causa.

Comment: Pois, a diferença é: existe um livro qualquer do século XV que fala dessa lenda em Portugal?, se sim nós sabemos que a lenda já existia em Portugal nessa altura. É obrigação de quem faz esses sites dar estas indicações. Quando não as dão, eu acho que aquilo é tudo invenção

Answer (score 1):

> La palabra "cornudo" está formada com raíces latinas y significa "que tiene los cachos grandes, que lo engaña la mujer".  Sus componentes léxicos son: cornu (cuerno), más el sufijo -udo (abundancia)  [**www.dechile.net**](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?cornudo)

**O uso de chifres como símbolo identificador daquele(a) que sofre infidelidade conjugal é um elemento de cultura latino. É tudo o que podemos afirmar.** Os Vikings usavam chifres como ornamento e  simbolo de bravura, sem nenhuma conotação insultuosa.  Já os italianos vem usando o termo "cornuto" com o significado pejorativo (traído pela mulher) há longa data. O mesmo termo ("cornudo" em português e espanhol) espalhou-se pelo Mediterrâneo, e daí para quase todos os países de língua portuguesa e espanhola. **O termo "cornudo", para a pessoa que sofre infidelidade conjugal, tem a mesma origem que o símbolo.** E existem diversas teorias, ou melhor ***lendas***, a respeito:

- A escolha do símbolo teria tido sua origem na Grécia antiga, mais precisamente na lenda do Minotauro que, segundo a mitologia grega, nasceu com um chifre por ter sido o fruto de uma relação, carnal e adúltera, de sua mãe com um touro.
- Uma segunda "lenda" é que o termo teria tido sua origem em Roma.  Os soldados romanos ao retornarem das guerras recebiam chifres de presente.  Isso simbolizaria a vitória na guerra, mas não tanto na cama junto às suas esposas.
- Outros "autores" citam que o símbolo foi adotado porque, assim como um animal não consegue ver seu chifre, a pessoa traída também não consegue vê-lo, sendo frequentemente a última a saber.
- Uma outra "teoria", e que até faz mais sentido, seria a de que na Europa medieval os senhores feudais tinham autoridade para dormir com qualquer mulher que residisse em suas terras, e os maridos simplesmente tinham que aceitar.  Para indicar que o senhor das terras estava "visitando" uma determinada morada e que, consequentemente, o marido deveria ficar afastado, um bom par de chifres era pendurado na porta de entrada.  Traduzido de [**Derecho de Pernada**](http://desconciertos3.blogspot.com.br/2010/03/relacion-verdadera-de-hipotesis-sobre.html) que não apresenta referências.

Quem pesquisar vai encontrar muitas outras estórias e lendas, mas nenhuma delas (e nem mesmo as quatro que postei) com referências fidedignas. Por esse motivo nem vale a pena citá-las.

**Quando encontramos fontes fidedignas, elas sempre são citadas. Infelizmente nem todas as palavras tem sua origem bem documentada. Mais difícil ainda quando se trata de atribuições pejorativas a uma palavra já existente, as quais certamente levam bem mais tempo a aparecer na mídia impressa.**

**ADDENDUM**

O [texto abaixo](http://www.parolacce.org/2009/04/18/perch-siamo-tutti-cornuti-parte-1/) foi copiado de um site que faz uma bela exposição sobre o assunto, relata o uso da palavra com conotação pejorativa já no século II, e cita uma referência bibliográfica.

> - Su Internet si trovano diverse spiegazioni fantasiose: dal mito di Minosse, che fu tradito dalla moglie Pasifae con un cornutissimo toro, all’imperatore Andronico Comneno che nel 12° secolo soleva appendere una testa di cervo nelle case dei mariti a cui rubava la moglie. Ma la prima ricostruzione è contraddittoria: il cornuto è il cornificatore (il toro) invece che il cornificato; e la seconda non regge, perché il termine “cornuto” è ben precedente al 12° secolo.
>     L’espressione, infatti, esisteva nella letteratura occidentale già da almeno un millennio. Il primo documento a citarlo è la [**“Onirocritica”**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneirocritica) del 2° secolo d.C.: una guida all’interpretazione dei sogni scritta dall’autore greco Artemidoro. In questo testo, “fare le corna” (riferito a una moglie) significa tradire il marito.

Artemidorus' Oneirocritica: Text, Translation, and Commentary (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2012). For an earlier English translation:

Comment: Numa questão de origem de expressões, precisamos de fontes, primeiros usos e datas.

Comment: @Jacinto   Acrescentei mais alguma coisa, mas certamente nenhuma informação definitiva sobre quando e onde.