# Qual a origem da palavra lenda?

Tags: etimologia

Uma lenda é uma história antiga que vai passando de geração em geração. Não sabemos o que é real quando se trata de uma lenda, pois elas geralmente eram contadas para explicar acontecimentos dos quais as pessoas não sabiam a causa.

No Brasil, as lendas são o resultado do contato entre as culturas indígenas, africanas e europeias que se encontraram no início da colonização.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), a palavra *lenda* vem do latim medieval *legenda* no sentido de ‘história da vida de santo’. Em português aparece primeiro *leenda* no século XIII, e só depois *lemda* e *lenda* já no século XV. Transcrevo o Houaiss, desabreviando algumas abreviaturas:

> **lenda** *s. f.* (sXIII cf. FichIVPM) **1** mesmo que *LEGENDA* (‘vida de santo’) **2** narrativa de carácter maravilhoso em que um facto histórico, centralizado em torno de algum herói popular (revolucionário, santo, guerreiro), se amplifica e se transforma sob o efeito da evocação poética ou imaginação popular **3** narrativa ou crendice acerca de seres maravilhosos e encantatórios, de origem humana ou não, existente no imaginário popular, que frequentemente explicam fenómenos da natureza <*a lenda da cobra d’água*>  → cf. *mito* **4** *por extensão* tradição popular <*uma cultura com raízes na lenda e não na ciência*> **5** *por extensão* mito popular de origem recente <*em torno desse hábil politico criou-se uma lenda que ele soube explorar muito bem*> […] ʘ ETIM latim medieval *legenda* ‘vida de santo’; ver *leg-*; fonte histórica sXIII *leenda* sXV *leemda* sXV *lemda* [...]

Literalmente, o latim *legenda* significava (ver comentário do Pablo) ‘(coisa) que se há de ler’, e como explica [Raphael Bluteau no seu *Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino* de 1716 (verbete *lenda*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=H-NBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA78&dq=%22chamadas%20lendas%20porque%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU0dzgjsnRAhVHOxQKHQVVCo0Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22chamadas%20lendas%20porque%22&f=false), “[a]s vidas dos Santos foraõ chamadas lendas porque se havião de ler na liçoens das Matinas, & nos refeitorios das Communidades”. Ora, procurei no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) e no Google Books, e até ao século XVIII, era precisamente quase sempre à vida de santos que se referia *lenda*, nas suas várias grafias. Os primeiros exemplos começam logo no século XIII [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/)) 
(ênfase minha em todas a citações):

> E depois frey Tomas de Cebrano, de mandada de aqueste manistro geerall, çerca de aquellas coussas que perteemçiam aa regra, compilou o primeiro trautado da **Leenda de sam Framçisco**
>   (Crónica da Ordem dos Frades Menores, 1209-85.)
>
> por que na **leenda do dicto sancto** [Vicente] fez meençom que dous corvos guardarom o sseu corpo das outras aves e cãães quando no campo foy lançado
>   (Dom Duarte, *Leal Conselheiro*, 1437/8.)

Nalguns poucos exemplos, de que este na [*Crónica Geral de Espanha*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_Geral_de_Espanha_de_1344) do Conde de Barcelos (originalmente composta em 1344) é o primeiro, *lenda* parece referir-se ao Corão e tradições religiosas muçulmanas:

> Senhor, eu sõõ natural desta cidade e meus avoos forõ daqui sempre [alfaqueques [Aulete]](http://www.aulete.com.br/alfaqueque). E eu, seendo moço pequeno, cativarõme cristããos. E fezme Deus tanta mercee e deume tal engenho que aprendi a [aljamya [Aulete]](http://www.aulete.com.br/aljamia) e toda a **leenda dos mouros**.

E ha também alguns exmplos poucos, começando na [*Crónica de Dom João I* de Fernão Lopes (1443)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B3nica_de_el-rei_D._Jo%C3%A3o_I), em *lenda* refere-se à vida de uma pessoa importante que não um santo:

> Rei de Portugual e primeiro do nome e segunda parte de sua **lemda**

Nos exemplos atá ao princípio do século XIX fica-se com a ideia que o escritor toma a lenda como verdadeira. Só a partir do século XIX é que se encontram escritores que claramente encaram as lendas de que escrevem como nós o fazemos hoje, ou seja como narrativas não verídicas. O primeiro exemplo claro que encontrei deste uso foi numa [tradução de 1841 por A. F. Castilho das *Metamophoses* de Ovídio](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1ktWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA303&dq=lenda&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAsfz_i8fRAhUIcRQKHQRVAoU4MhDoAQiAATAO#v=onepage&q=lenda&f=false):

> ¿ mas, porque razão, este bom de Ovidio, que tanto em amôres se delicía, passou por alto a Metamorphose, a que este Heróe volatil deveo o ser gerado, a Metamorphose de Jupiter em chuva de ouro ? Á fé, que mais guapa, e refulgente fábula, lh’a não poderia deparar toda a **lenda dos Deoses**

O seguinte é de 1865, as [*Lendas e Narrativas* de Alexandre Herculano:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=AURAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA73&dq=lenda&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjku6n0jcfRAhWM7RQKHR1ZB44Q6AEI8QEwHA#v=onepage&q=lenda&f=false)

> A **lenda** precedente é tirada das chronicas de Acenheiro, rol de mentiras e disparates publicado pela nossa Academia

---

Por curiosidade, até ao início do século XIX também se encontra *lenda* com o moderno sentido de *legenda*, ‘inscrição, texto explicativo que acompanha imagem’.

Comment: Na verdade *legenda*, em Latim, foi usada com o significado de "vida de santo" mas gramaticalmente é o particípio do futuro passivo do verbo *legere* "ler", isto é, *legenda* = "(coisa) que deve ser lida" (mesmo mecanismo gramatical que se encontra na palavra *agenda* = "(coisa) que deve ser feita".

Comment: @pablo Corrigi. Isso corresponde muito diretamente ao moderno *legenda* no português